# How can I feed two Marionette modules a piece of info from an appRoute?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I have an app with a `Sidebar`, which is its own module with its own region, and a `primaryRegion` that can show views from two other modules (a `Dashboard` view or a `Detail` view of an item selected from the sidebar).

When an item gets clicked in the `Sidebar`, it changes its display to show that it's been selected and gets displayed in the `primaryRegion`.

The problem I'm running into is that I've recently added routes to the app to directly display item details in the `primaryRegion` and I can't maintain this behavior when going directly to the `Detail` view for a given item.

**Given that only one module can respond to a route, how can I get the `Sidebar` to select the item designated in the URL and also display that item's `Detail` view in the `primaryRegion` without using a global object or introducing race conditions?**

Apologies for the lack of code, I'm having a hard time reducing it down to the essential parts while keeping it clear. Hopefully my description is good enough but if not please let me know and I'll provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options you could try:

1. Have `Detail` fire a global event when it renders, and have the `Sidebar` be listening for that event and highlight the correct item based on the data it gets from that event.
2. Or have your `Sidebar` handle the routing and use a variable route to determine what `Detail` to render. For example, have a route in the `Sidebar` of `'details/:id': showDetails'` and then a function like:

-

```
showDetails: function(id) {
  // highlight item with id === id here

  this.primaryRegion.show(new Details(id));
}
```